# How to change the font size of title?

Tags: titles

[image]

As shown from figure my thesis title. I want to increase or decrease the size to adjust the title in two or three rows. I have tried by putting `\Huge`, `\Large`, `\tiny` and many more command but no change occurs. please give me any good suggestion? The tex file also sent.

```
\begin{document}

\title{\vspace{-2in} \textbf{Development of a Pulsed Laser Deposition System and the Growth of Fluoride Thin Film}}

\author{
By\\ 
\Large
\vspace{-0.1in}\textbf{Maisum Ali}\\
\small
\vspace{+0.4in}\textbf{(PPHF13E020)}\\
\vspace{-0.4cm}\textsc{A thesis submitted in the partial fulfillment} \\
\vspace{-0.4cm}\textsc{of the requirement for the degree of}\\
\vspace{-0.4cm}\textsc{Master of Philosophy}\\
\vspace{+0.3in}\textsc{in Physics.}\\
Supervised by\\
\vspace{+0.3in}\textbf{Dr. Muhammad Anwar-ul-Haq}\\
\vspace{+0.3in}\includegraphics[scale=0.67]{UoSlogo}\\
\vspace{-0.4cm}\textsc{Department of Physics}\\
\vspace{-0.4cm}\textsc{University of Sargodha}\\
\vspace{-0.4cm}\textsc{Sargodha, Pakistan}
}
\date{\textbf{2016}}



\maketitle
```

Comment: Welcome, here is my standard link when it comes to titlepages: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: Write `\large` etc *inside* `\title`.

Comment: All this manual spacing ... Done on purpose? The output is very very very .... strange.

Comment: Which document class do you use? What are the dimensions (height, width) of the textblock?

Comment: Ah, double line spacing. Always bad on a titlepage.

Comment: start by removing _all_ the size and font changes, and `\vspace` from `\title` and `\author` that will allow the fonts used to be as specified by the document class. To change the fonts in structural elements you can then use the facilities of the document class you are using or several packages for that purpose, but the details depend on the document class which you have not shown.